# How to get multiple Random Values from Map ? - Dart

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

I trying to get some random multiple values from `map` as a list and there is some explanation in the code //, any logic if Function or like my logic down , thanks in advance

```
   class Test{
      String url;
      int id;
      String name;
      Test({required this.url , required this.id , required this.name});
    }
    
    class Fake{
      static List<Test> getSomeValues = [
        Test(id: 1 , url : "test/test" , name : "1Name"),
        Test(id: 2 , url : "test/test" , name : "2Name"),
        Test(id: 3 , url : "test/test" , name : "3Name"),
      ]; 
    }
    
    void widget(Test t){
      print(t.id);
      
    }
    
    void main(){
      print(Fake.getSomeValues.asMap().entries.where((f){
        // here just I can apply condition on each Value can't get random 
        return f.value.id == 1 ; 
        
      }).map((f){
         // I don't want not needy value arrive here .
        // after I want to use each instance of Test . 
        return widget(f.value);
      }).toList());
    }
```

e.g output:

```
void getRandom(List<test> t , int count){
// code
print(t.id)
}
getRandom(test , 2),
```

output :

```
3,1
```

Comment: you want to get random number using map?

Comment: if you logic return list that's fine :)

Comment: @Mo7ammed7amad updated my answer please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Please check

```
import 'dart:math';

class Test{
      String url;
      int id;
      String name;
      Test({this.url ,  this.id ,  this.name});
    }
    
    class Fake{
      static List<Test> getSomeValues = [
        Test(id: 1 , url : "test/test" , name : "1Name"),
        Test(id: 2 , url : "test/test" , name : "2Name"),
        Test(id: 3 , url : "test/test" , name : "3Name"),
        Test(id: 4 , url : "test/test" , name : "4Name"),
        Test(id: 5 , url : "test/test" , name : "5Name"),
        Test(id: 6 , url : "test/test" , name : "6Name"),
        Test(id: 7 , url : "test/test" , name : "7Name"),
      ]; 
    }
    
    
    
    void main(){
     List<Test>  itemOfList= shuffle(Fake.getSomeValues, 3);
      itemOfList.forEach((e)=> print(e.name));
    }

List<Test> shuffle(List<Test> items, int item) {
  var random = new Random();

  items.shuffle();

  return items.sublist(0, item);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I updated my question , check that if possible to get the idea

Comment: @Mo7ammed7amad do you want random list with specific item(like 2 , 3 or so on)